# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Tags: php

Выводит непонятную для меня ошибку:

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at L:\home\localhost\www\versal-anapa.ru\admin\manager.php:1) in L:\home\localhost\www\versal-anapa.ru\admin\lock.php on line 6
>   которая говорит, что не может поменять заголовок в файле.

Строки 6 и 7 в lock.php:

```
 Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
 Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
```

Что это означает? И как это исправить?

Comment: Что ж тут не понятного? Вы пробовали просто перевести это сообщение?

Comment: человек с терпением уже ответил на мой вопрос...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Помните, что header() обязана
> вызываться до отправки любого вывода:
> нормальными ли тэгами HTML, пустыми
> строками в файле или из PHP. Очень
> частой ошибкой является чтение кода
> функциями include() или require(), или
> другой функцией доступа к файлу, и
> наличие пробелов или пустых строк,
> которые выводятся до вызова header().
> Та же проблема возникает при
> использовании едингого PHP/HTML-файла.

http://www.php.su/header